# List become empty every time I add an Item on it from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I start learning asp.net core MVC for practice purposes I created one `HomeController` in which I have two methods

```
     [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
     public class HomeController : Controller
     {
        private readonly JobRepository _jobRepository;
        public HomeController()
        {
            _jobRepository = new JobRepository();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult AddJob(int job)
        {
            return Ok(_jobRepository.AddJob(job));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAllJobs()
        {
            return Ok(_jobRepository.GetAllJobs());
        }

    }
```

I am receiving data in my controller but the problem is when the data is transferred to my repository where I am saving all the Jobs in the int list

```
public class JobRepository
    {
        List<int> jobs  = new List<int>();

        public int AddJob(int job)
        {
            jobs.Add(job);
            return job;
        }

        public List<int> GetAllJobs()
        {
            return jobs;
        }
    }
```

The data is entered in the list but when I do another hit on my controller my list is reinitialized and the list count shows 1 in the immediate window

Comment: Can you show where and how you are using these two classes?

Comment: The first one is in HomeController class and the second class is completely I posted here

Comment: I added complete Controller Class code

Comment: @barzin.A I already tried it but this isn't worked for me

Comment: every time you call HomeController, a new jobRepo will be created. you should use Dependency Injection and Inject JobRepo into HomeController as a singelton

Comment: Do you want to use list of jobs as a database ?

Comment: No, I want to use them in In-Memory.
I added ```services.AddSingleton<JobRepository, JobRepository>();``` in Startup class ConfigureService method. but this is also not working

Comment: _"I added services.AddSingleton<JobRepository, JobRepository>(); in Startup class ConfigureService method"_ - that doesn't magically make `JobRepository` a singleton, you still need to inject it into your controller's constructor.

Comment: @CodeCaster I am injecting the instance in the Controller class please refer to the above code of HomeController Class

Comment: No, you're not, you're manually instantiating it with `new`. That is the opposite of injection.

Comment: _" I am injecting the instance in the Controller class"_ no you don't. You are creating one there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public HomeController()
{
// This instantiates a new instance of JobController,
// it >>does not<< inject one from DI.
    _jobRepository = new JobRepository();
}
```

This ignores your DI registration settings.

Instead do:

```
// Assuming JobRepository implements IJobRepository (which it should) 
// and it is registered in DI as 
// services.AddSingleton<IJobRepository, JobRepository>();
public HomeController( IJobRepository jobRepository )
{
    _jobRepository = jobRepository;
}
```

or without interface (which I wouldn't recommend):

```
public HomeController( JobRepository jobRepository )
{
    _jobRepository = jobRepository;
}
```

---

unrelated, I'd also recommend to add the null check

```
public HomeController( JobRepository jobRepository )
{
    _jobRepository = jobRepository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jobRepository));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your and all others who gave time on my question

Answer (score 0):

Each time you enter JobRepository it creates a new object of the List so it will be empty
If you want to store it temporally then make the object as static to avoid creating a new object each time

If you want persistence  you may want to use database and entityframework
Refer for documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: I want to keep data until my instance is running. I don't want to keep the data in the database

Comment: Then you seriously need to learn about how ASP.NET controller lifecycles work and how to store things in a session. Your "want" is DIRECTLY contradicting how ASP.NET works. Guess who wins. Hint: it is not you. Time to sit down, RTFM on lifecycle of controllers and come up with a solution that actually is feasible.